# Convert JSON with "string enum" properties to interface

Tags: json, typescript, enums

In our project, we are using [string enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums), to send the data from the BE to the client. Now the issue is, that when we mock the data, it contains the "enum strings" in the mock json files.

These mock json files are then imported like this: `import testJson from '.test.json';` ('resolveJsonModule' is enabled in tsconfig), which gives them a type 'based on the static JSON shape.' (See: [Resolve JSON Module](https://based%20on%20the%20static%20JSON%20shape.)).

Now the type which is generated for that enum property is string and not enum, so when I try to cast the json to the interface type, it throws me an error: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'testEnum'.`

Stackblitz example:

```
const testJSON = {
  name: 'hello World',
  enumProp: "MYTESTENUM_2",
};

enum testEnum {
  MYTESTENUM = "MYTESTENUM",
  MYTESTENUM_2 = "MYTESTENUM_2",
}

interface testinterface {
  name: string;
  enumProp: testEnum;
}

//const castJsonFile: testinterface = testJSON; // not compiling because the "string enums" cannot be converted
const castJsonFile: testinterface = testJSON as any;  // any cast is needed, to get it compiling, but looses all type safety


// Write TypeScript code!
const appDiv: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('app');
appDiv.innerHTML = (castJsonFile.enumProp === testEnum.MYTESTENUM_2) as any as string;
```

Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fjy8zs?file=index.ts

If I would not use "string enums" it would work fine, but this is a change which cannot be done.

Is there a way to tell typescript to treat the "string enums" as enums if he finds such a property in a JSON file?

Comment: Could you change every instance of "eneum" to "enum" here, unless there's a reason for the nonstandard spelling?

Comment: What would you like to see happen if the enum string in the JSON file doesn't match one of the enums?   Either you have to perform a runtime check that verifies the validity of the JSON, or you just want to have a compile-time *assertion* that it will be valid.  If it's an assertion, then you lose type safety, like `const castJsonFile = testJSON as TestInterface`, which isn't that much better than `as any`.  If it's a runtime check then you have to write such a check.  Can you clarify which general approach you're imagining here?

Comment: eneums are gone. Ideally I want the "name enums" to behave like default enums. meaning that a json file containing the value of a named enum is assignable to the enum and not detected as a string. But that might be a lot to ask. But e.g. if named enums are not used, like here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fjy8zs?file=index.ts it works like a charm without any casting

Comment: It's not working because the data type inferred from the JSON for the `enumProp` is `string`, which "contains" your enum (the code would work in the opposite direction: assigning the `enum` to a `string` type). The best you can do here is casting (not to `any`, but to `testinterface`: `const castJsonFile: testinterface = testJSON as testInterface;`

Comment: I was afraid of that. And your any cast example gives me an error too, sure that works?

Comment: [I don't see an error](https://tsplay.dev/m0yKPW) if you write `testJSON as testInterface`, can you produce a [mre] of the issue you're having?

Comment: could have sworn that did not work last time I tried. Thank you :)